# <Close by> and <Closer by>

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

When you want to say someone who lives far from you that it was better if they lived close to you, you would probabely say something like:

> I wish you lived **close by**.

But how about a comparative situation? Logically you should be able to say:

> I wish you lived **closer by**.

But [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lived+close+by%2Clived+closer+by&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clived%20close%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clived%20closer%20by%3B%2Cc0) shows almost no result for the "closer by" case! I wonder if there is a more common choice for that meaning in current English?

Comment: It's quite common to just drop the "by" after closer.

Comment: Or *I wish you lived closer* ***to me***. Although *closer by* isn't wrong (you can say it), it's not normally used.